# How does a single-threaded queue with a dummy node facilitate concurrency?

Tags: c++, list, multithreading, concurrency, queue

In Anthony Williams' C++ Concurrency in Action book, the following single-threaded queue is shown:

```
template<typename T>
class queue {
public:
    queue() : 
        head{new node}, tail{head.get()} {}
    

    queue(const queue& other)=delete;
    queue& operator=(const queue& other)=delete;

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop() {
        if(head.get()==tail) {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        }
        
        std::shared_ptr<T> const res(head->data);
        std::unique_ptr<node> old_head=std::move(head);
        head=std::move(old_head->next);
        return res;
    }

    void push(T new_value) {
        std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)));
        std::unique_ptr<node> p(new node);

        tail->data=new_data;
        std::cout << tail << *(head->data) << '\n';
        std::cout << tail << *(tail->data) << '\n';

        node* const new_tail=p.get();
        tail->next=std::move(p);
        tail=new_tail;
    }

    struct node {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    node* tail;
};
```

This queue uses a dummy node for the head and tail, and says the advantage of this is that push() only ever touches the `tail` node now and not the `head` node (so when we go to add mutexes, we only need a mutex for the head node).

But how is this true if the queue is empty, and the first push takes place? My understanding is, if `tail` is set to `head.get()`, they are holding the same pointer, and on the first update to `tail->data`, the head pointer is also affected.

And indeed, with my print statements we see the following when we try to push to the queue twice:

```
0x55c37e5fa2701
0x55c37e5fa2701
0x55c37e5fa2b01
0x55c37e5fa2b02
```

Showing that head and tail share an address on the first push, but no longer on the second.

Am I misunderstanding this in some way, or are `head` and `tail` in fact the same on a push to an empty queue?

Comment: Re, "on the first update to `tail->data`, the head pointer is also affected." No. The `push` operation never changes the head pointer. It changes the _node_ to which the head pointer points, but it never changes the pointer itself. Likewise the `pop` operation never changes the `tail` pointer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sure, but still if the queue has one element, then `head.get() == tail` is `true`. So then when we update `tail->data` on the first push, isn't `head->data` also changed? Doesn't this need to be protected in some way?

Comment: Not claiming to completely understand the issues, but I see that `pop` never changes the content of a node, although, on the other hand, it does _delete_ the node. I'm going to decline to write a real answer for this one. I came to C++ from Java land, and I never could grok `std::move` nor, why anybody would use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: No worries. Both those subjects are more dense than I can explain fully in a comment, but I'll try: 

- `std::move()` should really be named something like `std::allow_to_be_moved()`. Formally, it converts the value passed to it into an `rvalue`, which allows the `unique_ptr` move assignment operator to be called instead of its copy assignment operator.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is used to give exclusive ownership of some resource to someone, enforcing only one reference exists to something at a time. It takes care of releasing memory (or whatever resource it's holding onto if you pass it a custom deleter) when it goes out of scope. I can think of a lot of cases, like various data containers, where you'd want the container to have exclusive control over the memory, it's actually harder for me to think of `shared_ptr` use cases. Also, `std::move()` must be used to assign `unique_ptr`s because they can't be copied, since they signify exclusive ownership.

Comment: You miss my point. I know what `unique_ptr` _does._ What I don't understand is why you would ever use it. If my algorithm only needs to keep one reference to something, then I write the code that keeps only one. I don't write code to _enforce_ that there can only be one. Destructors and value semantics are foreign to an old Java programmer, but at least I can understand them. `move` is different. When they added `move` and r-value references, all I could think was, "OMG! The language lawyers are running the asylum."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Figured out the answer to my own question)

Introducing a dummy node resolves the issue because:

- If the queue has zero elements, `try_pop()` will return immediately and never attempt to access `head -> next`. Therefore, `head->next` and `tail->next` will never be accessed simultaneously when they point to the same value.
- If the queue has one element, `head` and `tail` are now separate elements. `head` is the first element in the queue, and `tail` is the next element, which is a dummy node. Again, there is no situation where `head->next` and `tail->next` are both accessed when they point to the same value.